# How to marker search become draggable and give the Longitude & latitude in leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I want my leaflet map able to drag the marker and get the longitude and latitude. The marker show from search result. Here my js code but I'm stuck T^T please help me. Thank you

and here my HTML for address and Latitude Longitude

```
<form>
 <p>
    <label for="address">Address</label>
    <input id="address">
  </p>

   <p>
      <label for="latitude">Lintang</label>
      <input id="latitude" placeholder="-6.922045042885848">
   </p>

    <p>
      <label for="longitude">Bujur</label>
      <input id="longitude" placeholder="107.61605564716159">
    </p>
</form>

<div class="frame-lokasi">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

here my js

```
var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [-6.922045042885848, 107.61605564716159],
        zoom: 18
    });

    L.control.scale().addTo(map);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    var searchControl = new L.esri.Controls.Geosearch().addTo(map);

    var results = new L.LayerGroup('resuls', {draggable: true}).addTo(map);

    var marker = L.marker([-6.922045042885848, 107.61605564716159], {
        draggable: true
    }).addTo(map);

    marker.on('dragend', function (e) {
        document.getElementById('latitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lat;
        document.getElementById('longitude').value = marker.getLatLng().lng;
    });

    searchControl.on('results', function(e){
        results.clearLayers();
        for (var i = e.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            results.addLayer(L.marker(e.results[i].latlng));
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function(){$('.pointer').fadeOut('slow');},3400);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this line: `results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng));`

```
searchControl.on('results', function(e) {
    results.clearLayers();
    for (var i = e.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var searchMarker = L.marker(data.results[i].latlng, {
            draggable: true
        });
        document.getElementById('latitude').value = searchMarker.getLatLng().lat; 
        document.getElementById('longitude').value = searchMarker.getLatLng().lng;

        searchMarker.on('dragend', function(e) {
            console.log(e);
            var _marker = e.target;
            console.log(_marker.getLatLng())
            document.getElementById('latitude').value = _marker.getLatLng().lat; 
            document.getElementById('longitude').value = _marker.getLatLng().lng;
        })
        results.addLayer(searchMarker);
    }
});
```

And is `data.results` a typo? `L.marker(data.results[i].latlng, {` data is nowhere defined maybe `e.results`

Comment: do I add that inside "for" or I delete that then create new variable?

Comment: yes, that typo but still didn't work in my maps after I update it

Comment: Do you get an error in the console? `F12` -> `console`. Also you have an error while Layergroup creation, use `var results = new L.LayerGroup([], {draggable: true}).addTo(map);`

Comment: omg thats work ^^, but how can i get longitude and latitude separate for call in HTML form ?

Comment: like you already have in your code with `document.getElementById('latitude').value = _marker.getLatLng().lat; document.getElementById('longitude').value = _marker.getLatLng().lng;`. Also please Accept the answer :)

Comment: yes, but I mean they didn't immediately show the long lat and I must drag it first to show the actual number. anyway, thank you so so so much >.<

Comment: okay, thank you so much >,< you're my savior